# Issues wih addCondition in validformbuilder in php

Tags: php, validform

I have implemented creating embed form using validformbuilder in Php. Its Working fine. But when I Adding multiple condition for fields. I get blank form. This is the sample code

```
        $objFirstName = $objForm->addField('firstname', 'First name', ValidForm::VFORM_STRING);
        $objLastName = $objForm->addField('lastname', 'Last name', ValidForm::VFORM_STRING);
        $objFirstName->addCondition(
            'visible', // Last name will become
            false, // 'not visible' (visible -> false)
            array(
                // When field $objFirstName 'is equal to' Robin
                new \ValidFormBuilder\Comparison($objLastName, ValidForm::VFORM_COMPARISON_EQUAL, 'Robin1')
            )
        );
        $objLastName->addCondition(
            'visible', // Last name will become
            false, // 'not visible' (visible -> false)
            array(
                // When field $objFirstName 'is equal to' Robin
                new \ValidFormBuilder\Comparison($objFirstName, ValidForm::VFORM_COMPARISON_EQUAL, 'Robin')
            )
        );
```

The issue happened when adding condition for already condition added fields. For example Here i added condition for first name. Then i added condition for last name with respect to first name. This creates issue for me. Please help me

Comment: If it's empty, you probably get a PHP error. Can you post that here? Check your logs.

Comment: Actually there not sowing any errors. Just a blank page

Comment: When i checking this code creating issue in $strValue = $this->__subject->__getValue(true, $intDynamicPosition); in check function in Comparison.php file. When i replace the true value with false its working fine. So let me know this will create any other issues

Comment: Try stepping through the code (xdebug) to detect why you get a blank output. Blank page = something went wrong.